# In App Purchases - high percentage of failed purchases - SKError code 2 or 0

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

We are facing a serious issues with in app purchases in our app.

We offer 3 IAP: auto-renewable subscription 3M, auto-renewable subscription 1Y, non-consumable one-time purchase (LifeTime access)

In our case 70-80% of transactions fail and we mostly get SKError code=0 or code=2 - Cannot connect to iTunes Store. According to SKError documentation it's unknown error (code 0) or cancelled transaction (error 2).

Sometime purchase fails several times for the same user so it’s very hard to believe that user intentionally cancels transaction for the same product 3 or 4 times in a row.

It happens regardless iOS version, device model, our app version.
Below is our code used to fetch products and make a transaction.

We've checked multiple threads with the same issue but coudn't find any solution.

We do not offer any promotions, product identifiers are valid...
Some users are able to make a purchases without any issues.

Any ideas?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyStoreKit
import StoreKit

final class IAPService: NSObject {

    static let shared = IAPService()
    public var isSubscriptionAvailable = false

    private var identifiers = ["product_x_id",
                               "product_y_id",
                               "product_z_id"]
    var products: [SKProduct] = []
    var purchaseProducts: [PurchaseProduct] = []

    private var successBlock: ((String?,String?)->())? //product Id, receipt
    private var errorBlock: ((String)->())?

    private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    private var productsRequestCompletionHandler: (()->())?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        self.loadProducts()
    }


    func loadProducts(completion: (()->())? = nil) {
        productsRequest?.cancel()
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = completion

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(identifiers))
        productsRequest?.delegate = self
        productsRequest?.start()
    }

    func purchaseProduct(identifier: String, onSuccess: ((String?,String?) -> ())?, onError: ((String?)  -> ())?) {
        guard products.count > 0 else {
            loadProducts {
                self.purchaseProduct(identifier: identifier, onSuccess: onSuccess, onError: onError)
            }
            return
        }
        guard let product = self.products.first(where: { (skProduct) -> Bool in
            return skProduct.productIdentifier == identifier
        }) else {
            onError?("IAP error: cannot find product id")
            return
        }
        clearHandlers()
        self.successBlock = onSuccess
        self.errorBlock = onError

        print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    public func restorePurchases(onSuccess: ((String?,String?) -> ())?, onError: ((String?)  -> ())?) {
        clearHandlers()
        self.successBlock = onSuccess
        self.errorBlock = onError
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    public func fetchReceipt(productId: String) {
        SwiftyStoreKit.fetchReceipt(forceRefresh: false) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let receiptData):
                self.successBlock?(productId, receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: []))
                self.clearHandlers()
                break
            case .error(let error):
                print("Receipt verification failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                self.errorBlock?(error.localizedDescription)
                self.clearHandlers()
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func clearHandlers() {
        successBlock = nil
        errorBlock = nil
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
        productsRequest = nil
    }
}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Loaded list of products...")
        let skProducts = response.products

        skProducts.forEach { (skProduct) in
            products.append(skProduct)
        }
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?()
        clearHandlers()
    }

    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to load list of products: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?()
        clearHandlers()
    }
}


extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                             updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                complete(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                fail(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                restore(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("complete...")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

        print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("fail...")
        var failureReason: String = ""

        if let skError = transaction.error as? SKError {
            switch skError.code {  // https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skerror.code
            case .unknown:
                failureReason = "Unknown or unexpected error occurred"
                break
            case .paymentCancelled:
                failureReason = "Payment cancelled by user"
                break
            case .clientInvalid:
                failureReason = "Invalid Client"
                break
            case .paymentInvalid:
                failureReason = "Invalid Payment"
                break
            case .paymentNotAllowed:
                failureReason = "Payment not allowed"
                break
            case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed:
                failureReason = "Cloud service network connection failed"
                break
            case .cloudServicePermissionDenied:
                failureReason = "Cloud service permission denied"
                break
            case .storeProductNotAvailable:
                failureReason = "Store product not available"
                break
            case .cloudServiceRevoked:
                failureReason = "Cloud service revoked"
                break
            case .privacyAcknowledgementRequired:
                failureReason = "Privacy Acknowledgement Required"
                break
            case .unauthorizedRequestData:
                failureReason = "Unauthorized Request Data"
                break
            case .invalidOfferIdentifier:
                failureReason = "Invalid offer identifier"
                break
            case .invalidSignature:
                failureReason = "Invalid signature"
                break
            case .missingOfferParams:
                failureReason = "Missing offer params"
                break
            case .invalidOfferPrice:
                failureReason = "Invalid offer price"
                break
            }
            failureReason += " code: \(skError.code.rawValue)"
        }
        else if let isCancelledError = transaction.error?.isCancelledError, isCancelledError == true {
            failureReason = "isCancelledError"
        }
        else {
            failureReason = "\(transaction.error.debugDescription)"
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

        errorBlock?(failureReason)
        self.clearHandlers()
    }

    private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
        guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

        fetchReceipt(productId: identifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Well the `code=2` is cancelled like you said, so nothing to worry about there. The `code=0` is more unclear. Apple says "When this error occurs in production, it may indicate a problem with the user’s iTunes account."

Comment: are all these logging for errors sent to a database like Firebase? Curious how the 70-80% failure are known.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you solve this issue @Magda? We have exactly the same issue and we need help. Some of our users in production get SKError code=0 and the amount is as you described high.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue where I get either error code 0 or error code 2 (usually the error code 2 is triggered even when the purchase was successful) and been e-mailing back and forth with Apple's Developer Technical Support for the past few months on this one.

It looks to be a known issue which happens for certain apps with Apple currently, the best thing to do in your case would be to raise a Technical Support Incident (TSI) for code-level support from Apple directly.

Alternatively you can also use the feedback assistant to raise a bug report.

Unfortunately this seems to be something caused on the Store Kit/App Store side and requires Apple to look into it on a case-by-case basis where it does occur.