# How to accept “Apple Media Services Terms and Conditions" for TestFlight/IAP when it always gives an "no connection" error?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight

I am testing an app with in-app-purchases via TestFlight.

Recently, when I try to test buying an in-app-purchase, a prompt "Apple Media Services Terms and Conditions have changed” started to appear which is always followed by an error “no connection” (internet connection is working fine).

How can one resolve this situation and get back to a working setup for testing in-app-purchases?

I already tried this to no avail:

- different internet connection/type
- deleting the app and re-installing
- restarting the device, using another device
- signing out of iCloud and back in again
- checked regular App Store purchases are working fine, problem only occurs in the sandbox environment

[image]
[image]

Comment: I experienced the same thing yesterday. Unfortunately, I did not manage to resolve the issue.

Comment: I asked around and 4 other developers confirmed having the same issue for weeks now. I submitted a TSI on this.

Comment: Also, FB9966021.

Comment: Ralf and @JMIT, Was there any outcome on the TSI please? I have the same problem, how did you solve it please? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

- every time press Cancel button , for 4-5 times
- at 6th time press OK button , 2nd window will open , press retry, nothing       will happen , wait for some time. force close the app
- terms and condition popup will occur , an you can able to click agree button here now

It worked for me , I hope this will also worked for you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The moment I force close the app, everything is off the memory and I need to start the app again via Xcode? But then I lost the state in the process.  How did you solve this? Thanks